# string.h not necessary in a C code

Tags: c, string, header-files

I'm coding in C and I realize a program like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char name[100];

    printf("What's your name ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf(hi %s, nic to meet you !", name);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that I realized that without the string.h, the program work when it's not supposed to because there is a string. Can someone explain me why it works?

Comment: The easiest way to determine what headers will be required is simply to take each function you use and `man functionname` (or `whatis functionname` if your distro doesn't provide a pager). Then just look at the top of the `man` page. It will tell you what headers are required. You are only using *standard I//O* functions, therefore only `stdio.h` is required in your present code. You can also do `man headername` (e.g. `man string.h`) to see what functions are provided by that header.

Answer (score 0):

You only used `printf()` and `scanf()` in your code. They are both declared in `stdio.h`.

"There is a string" does not imply that "string.h must be included". "Refer to a data type or function declared in string.h" does.

Comment: But there is a data type in my code and it is the char, right?

Comment: `char` is a language key word; an intrinsic type.   You don't need to include any headers for it.

Comment: But there is a possibility to avoid using `<string.h>` for certain compilers. See commit, which fixed compiler errors for cross-compiling on android, which added `<string.h>`: https://github.com/linux-test-project/ltp/commit/4053a2551b926d372dd47485f7381ec3fa19772a. Although not mentioned in commit message, these fixes were not needed for normal (native) compilation with both `gcc` and `clang`.